# Error: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Data Frames:

prev_df:

```
       Time       FO_SYMBOL  TOTAL_VOLUME
0  14:20:41             ACC        6778.0
1  14:56:57        ADANIENT        4314.0
2  09:19:12      AUROPHARMA        1295.0
3  15:09:14      BAJAJ-AUTO        8339.0
4  09:19:12         HCLTECH        1431.0
5  09:19:12      HEROMOTOCO        1551.0
6  13:53:02      ULTRACEMCO        8284.0
```

df:

```
       Time       FO_SYMBOL  TOTAL_VOLUME
0  14:20:41             ACC        6778.0
1  14:56:57        ADANIENT        4314.0
2  09:19:12      AUROPHARMA        1295.0
3  15:09:14      BAJAJ-AUTO        8339.0
4  09:19:12         HCLTECH        1431.0
5  09:19:12      HEROMOTOCO        1551.0
6  13:53:02      ULTRACEMCO        8284.0
7  14:55:12      BHEL              8114.0 <<= NEW ROW
8  14:55:12      BHEL              8120.0 <<= NEW ROW
```

I want to compare both dataframe and find the new rows which are different. I want my output as below:

Result:

```
0  14:55:12      BHEL              8114.0 <<= NEW ROW
1  14:55:12      BHEL              8120.0 <<= NEW ROW
```

Currently I am using code as below:

```
indexes = (df != prev_df).any(axis=1)
new_df = df.loc[indexes]
```

But when new rows populated in `df` the I am getting error as:

> Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
cols=prev_df.columns.intersection(df.columns).tolist()
pd.concat([df, pd.concat([prev_df]*2)]).drop_duplicates(cols, keep=False)
```

---

```
       Time FO_SYMBOL  TOTAL_VOLUME
7  14:55:12      BHEL        8114.0
8  14:55:12      BHEL        8120.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df3 = pd.merge(df,prev_df,on='a',how='left',indicator=True)
df3[df3['_merge']=='left_only']
df3.drop(['_merge'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
      Time FO_SYMBOL  TOTAL_VOLUME
7  14:55:12      BHEL        8114.0
8  14:55:12      BHEL        8120.0
```

Comment: @anky_91 you were right thanks for correcting me